# Running solidity-coverage with truffle gives error: can not find 'coverageEnv/migrations'

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

Running solidity-coverage gives the following error:

```
$npm run coverage
...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts


Launched testrpc on port 8555
Running: node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage ../tests/test0.js
(this can take a few seconds)...
Using network 'coverage'.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/solo/git/my-contract/coverageEnv/migrations'
Cleaning up...
Shutting down testrpc-sc (pid 5715)
Event trace could not be read.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './allFiredEvents'
Exiting without generating coverage...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-contract@0.0.1 coverage: `solidity-coverage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-contract@0.0.1 coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/solo/.npm/_logs/2018-10-07T17_16_27_017Z-debug.log
```

.solcover.js

```
module.exports = {
    copyPackages: ['zeppelin-solidity'],
    compileCommand: 'node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile --network coverage',
    testCommand: 'node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage ../tests/test0.js',
    port: '8555',
    skipFiles: []
};
```

truffle-config:
...

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ...
    coverage: {
      host: 'localhost',
      network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
      port: 8555,
      gas: 0xfffffffffff,
      gasPrice: 0x01,
    }
  },
};
```

Running the testrpc and the test manually works just fine. But when running with solidity-coverage, for some reason it can't find the `migrations` dir in `coverageEnv`.

Any indication would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Although there might be a more elegant way to fix it, I managed to workaround this issue by copying the migrations scirpt as part of the testCommand: `testCommand: 'cp -a ../migrations ../coverageEnv && node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage ../tests/test0.js',`

Answer (score 0):

Solidity-coverage creates a temporary directory based on your folder directory, I reccomend changing your test command to just be a path to your tests directory instead to a specific file.

Generally I use openzeppelin-solidity instead of zeppelin-solidity.

What is your file directory like?

Comment: Using a path to a single test is only used to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In file `.solcover.js`:

1. Change `zeppelin-solidity` to `openzeppelin-solidity`
2. Change `.bin/truffle` to `truffle/build/cli.bundled.js` (2 occurrences)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but they are not related to the issue.